# Installing VPython in Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, vpython

So, i've just startet university, and we have to install python.
Thats fine, cause it's build-in to OSX (Snow Leopard).
I have installed matplotlib, numpy and scipy using this : http://stronginference.com/scipy-superpack/
It works perfectly, and i don't have to install the python.org version.
But, now we have to install VPython, wich requires the python.org version (2.7)
I just wanna know if it's possible to install just the library's in the apple version of python (2.6.1)

Regards, Adam.

Comment: Any updates on if you've found a nice method for this? I was trying to decide which of the two methods Jacob mentions (Install Python2.7 somewhere else or install the *nix source of VPython) when I found this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated software with a complicated build process, so first and foremost I'd advice you to save yourself some trouble and compile your own Python 2.7 and install it as a user somewhere under your home directory / install the MacOS X binary of 2.7 (probably also as a user under your home directory, but I'm less sure about that) [1]. VPython is complicated software and if they explicitly say that the want 2.7 in their docs they probably have a good reason. It *might* be possible but I'd expect various problems when trying with another version than their recommended one.

But if you really want to have a shot, what they call their 'Linux' download is actually their source tree. Download and try to build that with your custom build/installation of Python as basis.

[1] Compiling Python is a great learning experience, especially in combination with  [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [Distrubute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute). Multiple isolated Python's FTW.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ill try to compile myself, and add the necessary librarys afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [macports](http://www.macports.org/), [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install python 2.7. Following that, you should be able to use setuptools to install matplotlib, scipy and then vpython.